# for event in pygame.event.get(): not working

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have the following code:

```
while OS_ON:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        OS_ON = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if x > 63 and x < 143 and y > 298 and y < 378:
            Calculator = True
            while Calculator:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        OS_ON = False
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                        if x > 180 and x < 218 and y > 670 and y < 708:
                            Calculator = False
```

In my first loop the `for event in pygame.event.get():` works but when I use it again in my second loop I does not work anymore. Do you know how to fix it so it works in booth loops.

Comment: When you catch yourself repeating lines like `for event in pygame.event.get():`, you should probably consider restructuring your code in a more fundamental way. Make functions rather than one big, nested loop for instance.

Comment: @jDo can you give me an example of a function please?

Comment: There are multiple pygame questions on SO that do similar things and include lots of nice code. Search and you'll find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3.x, `pygame.event.get()` was made a generator, so once you retrieve a value from it, it's gone for good. You can try saving its content into a list first:

```
while OS_ON:
    events = list(pygame.event.get())
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            OS_ON = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x > 63 and x < 143 and y > 298 and y < 378:
                Calculator = True
                while Calculator:
                    for event2 in events: # 'event' is used in the outer loop
                        if event2.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            OS_ON = False
                        if event2.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                            if x > 180 and x < 218 and y > 670 and y < 708:
                                Calculator = False
```

But if you really need to do something like this, then you really need to redesign your code such that it makes use of only one `pygame.event.get()` every frame.

Comment: Indentation is off

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. Nothing has changed with `pygame.event.get()` when released for python 3.x. It still returns a simple list.

Comment: Ah, I did see myself, and it seems you are correct. Perhaps `pygame.event.get()` returns a list after flushing it; just like what happens with `SDL_PumpEvents()`. If you know what exactly it might be then, I'd appreciate if you'd share your knowledge.